# Submissão Ajax - Enter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Como posso fazer uma submissão com ajax usando a tecla enter? 
Ou seja, possuo o seguinte código:

```js
 var nome = $("#nome").val();
 jQuery.ajax({
             method: "get",
             url: "teste.php",
             data: { "nome": nome },
             success: function(data){
                 alert("Enviado com Sucesso!");
             }
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu Nome">
<button>Enviar</button>
```

Como posso fazer, para que ao estar focado no input quando for pressionado a tecla enter seja submetido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
$('#nome').on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.which !== 13) return;
  var nome = this.value;
  jQuery.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: "teste.php",
    data: {
      "nome": nome
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Enviado com Sucesso!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu Nome">
<button>Enviar</button>
```

O importante é procurar o código da tecla que foi pressionada, 13 para Enter.

Explicação:

- `$('#nome').on('keyup', function(event) {` - quando o elemento com o ID `nome` receber o input de uma tecla (no momento de largar a tecla) esse corre uma função

A função chamada pelo `.on('keyup'` recebe automaticamente o argumento `event` que contém informação sobre o evento do teclado, neste caso o numero da tecla pressionada. Se o `event.which` for `13` esse é o código da tecla enter e sabemos então que essa tecla foi pressionada.

Essa função tem como `this` o elemento que recebeu o evento. Por isso o `this.value` dá-nos o valor atual do elemento.

Comment: Você pode explicar como funciona o código?Pelo menos este código: $('#nome').on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.which !== 13) return;
  var nome = this.value;

Comment: @CarlosHenrique sim, claro! 1 min

Comment: @CarlosHenrique atualizei agora!

Comment: o .wich o que significa? E para que serve?

Comment: @CarlosHenrique esse `event` é um objeto que o JavaScript nos dá. O jQuery dá mais algumas propriedades a esse objeto, neste caso o `which` é uma propriedade nativa mas que o jQuery normaliza. Ou seja, em alguns browsers que não têm esse `which` o jQuery dá-lhe um valor na mesma, para ser sempre o mesmo em qualquer browser. Se usares código nativo o `event.key` é mais correto. Mas em jQuery o `.which` é o que deves usar.